# Java apns payload not shows in distribution in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification

There is strange issue. 
iOS app's Notification working in development. Also working in distribution. 
Not issue with token or profile.

But there is one notification payload working in development build but not in distribution.

Sending payload by Java apns 2.4.0

And payload has alert and other json data too. 
It was working before, but one updated with iOS 10, it stop receiving.

I had checked with apple remote Notification guideline, I see

I have been in  trouble. 
Please suggest any way to come out from this situation.

Comment: check the apns production certificate to be valid. maybe its helps